# How to call singleton here? ios7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, singleton

If I create an instance of singleton class in MyViewController, how then to call singleton from MyViewController? Like class method or like instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a singleton in objective-C you need to to this:

```
@interface gaSharedData : NSObject
+ (gaSharedData *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

in the .h file of the singleton class. In the .m file you need:

```
static gaSharedData *sharedObject = nil;

+ (gaSharedData *)sharedInstance
{
   static dispatch_once_t _singletonPredicate;

    dispatch_once(&_singletonPredicate, ^{
       sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedObject;
}

- (id)init {
    return self;
}
```

Now if you want to get an instance of the class gaSharedData, you need to call this like that:

```
gaSharedData *data = [gaSharedData sharedInstance];
```

I hope this helps you :)